# Blender UV Map collapses into one small dot in UV Editor

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, objects

I'm trying to unwrap the mesh. It appears as very small dot in the down left corner in the UV Editor and I can not make it significantly bigger.
The texture also does not appear on the object.
I tried marking seams but it does not make a difference.

It works just fine with all other objects in the scene.

Thank you for the help:)
[image: UV Map as a small dot inside 3D cursor in UV Editor]

Comment: probably you need a blend file to find out. Until then, try to select all the points of your object and press "U" twice

Comment: Select dot in uv editor, right click and unwrap.